# Android Studio database

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone I am new in Java programming and in the android studio environment and I need your help.
I am building an application that demands storing records of appointments into a database. I have created navigation between the activity's and I have also create a class named `DBhandler` which is about create update and delete records so far so good but the moment I add the following part of code in the activity that is about to create a new row in the database:

```
DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
db.NewApointment(new Apointments(23123,text2,text3,text4,text5));
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Create_Apointment.this, Records.class);
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The application for some reason stops working. I did research for my problem but I did not found anything similar to my problem, could it be a bug of android studio or am I missing something? I will show you my whole code just make to easier to you

This is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void CreateApo(View view)
    {
        Intent i =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, Create_Apointment.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void Edit_Apointment(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Records.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the activity which is used to store a new appointment

```
public class Create_Apointment extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText editText4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    String text2= editText.getText().toString();
    String text3= editText2.getText().toString();
    String text4= editText3.getText().toString();
    String text5= editText4.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create__apointment);
    }

    public void back(View view)
    {
        Intent i =  new Intent(Create_Apointment.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void Create(View view)
    {
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
        db.NewApointment(new Apointments(23123,text2,text3,text4,text5));
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Create_Apointment.this, Katagrafes.class);   

        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

The following code is for the management of the database

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    //DATABASE NAME
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="APOINTMENTINFO";
    private static final String APOINTMENT_TABLE="APOINTMENTS";
    //Column NAMES
    private static final String KEY_ID="id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME="Name";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS="Address";
    private static final String KEY_PLACE="Place";
    private static final String KEY_WRA="WRA";
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String Create_APOINTMENTS_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE"+ APOINTMENT_TABLE + "(" +     KEY_ID +"INTERGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_NAME + "TEXT," +KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT," + KEY_PLACE+"TEXT,"+ KEY_WRA+"TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(Create_APOINTMENTS_TABLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + APOINTMENT_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add-insert new apointment
    public void NewApointment(Apointments apointments)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, apointments.getName()); //ONOMA RADEVOY
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, apointments.getAddress());// adress
        values.put(KEY_PLACE, apointments.getPlace());//meros
        values.put(KEY_WRA, apointments.getWraRad());//wra
        db.insert(APOINTMENT_TABLE, null ,values);
        db.close();
    }
    // read 1 record
    public Apointments getApointment(int id )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(APOINTMENT_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID,  KEY_NAME,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_PLACE,KEY_WRA},KEY_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null );
        if (cursor !=null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        Apointments contact = new  Apointments(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
        //return apointment
        return  contact;
    }
    public List<Apointments> getAllApointments()
    {
        List<Apointments> apointmentsList= new ArrayList<Apointments>();
        //selection of all querys
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ APOINTMENT_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                Apointments apointments = new  Apointments(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return apointmentsList;
    }
    public int  updateApointment(Apointments apointments)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME,apointments.getName());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS,apointments.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PLACE,apointments.getPlace());
        values.put(KEY_WRA,apointments.getWraRad());
        //update row
        return db.update(APOINTMENT_TABLE,values, KEY_ID + " =?", new String[]  {String.valueOf(apointments.getId())} );
    }

    //delete records
    public void deleteapoitnments (Apointments apointments)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(APOINTMENT_TABLE,KEY_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(apointments.getId())} );
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Also I have create a class named "`appointments`" to refer an appointment as an object in my application.

```
public class Apointments {

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private String Place;
    private String WraRad;

    public Apointments(int id, String Name, String Address, String Place, String WraRad )
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.Name=Name;
        this.Address=Address;
        this.Place=Place;
        this.WraRad=WraRad;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name=Name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address=Address;
    }
    public void setPlace(String Place) {
        this.Place=Place;
    }
    public void setWraRad(String WraRad) {
        this.WraRad=WraRad;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public String getAddress()
    {
        return Address;
    }
    public String getPlace()
    {
        return Place;
    }
    public String getWraRad()
    {
        return WraRad;
    }

}
```

My logCat says the following:

```
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm:   VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0ac7
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm:  Could not find method android.app.Activity.getReferrer, referenced from method  com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 74: Landroid/app/Activity;.getReferrer  ()Landroid/net/Uri;
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0b3b
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 517: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0bb8
    08-30 16:34:26.479 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteractionRoot, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 98: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteractionRoot ()Z
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0be0
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isDestroyed, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 93: Landroid/app/Activity;.isDestroyed ()Z
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0beb
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 236 (Landroid/os/UserHandle;) in Lcom/example/dim/myapplication/Create_Apointment;
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0c3b
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 504: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0c68
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 236 (Landroid/os/UserHandle;) in Lcom/example/dim/myapplication/Create_Apointment;
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0ca4
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getMediaController, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 68: Landroid/app/Activity;.getMediaController ()Landroid/media/session/MediaController;
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0cac
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAffinity, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 48: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAffinity ()V
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0cb2
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getSearchEvent, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 77: Landroid/app/Activity;.getSearchEvent ()Landroid/view/SearchEvent;
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d2b
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V from Lcom/example/dim/myapplication/Create_Apointment;)
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2396: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.onReallyStop ()V
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d6b
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.isVoiceInteraction, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 97: Landroid/app/Activity;.isVoiceInteraction ()Z
    08-30 16:34:26.489 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ddb
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestVisibleBehind, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 169: Landroid/app/Activity;.requestVisibleBehind (Z)Z
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e40
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 199: Landroid/app/Activity;.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e55
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onProvideAssistData, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 141: Landroid/app/Activity;.onProvideAssistData (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e6a
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAndRemoveTask, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 50: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAndRemoveTask ()V
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0e92
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 425: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0ee9
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.onNavigateUp, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 131: Landroid/app/Activity;.onNavigateUp ()Z
     08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0efa
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.reportFullyDrawn, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 167: Landroid/app/Activity;.reportFullyDrawn ()V
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0f17
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getParentActivityIntent, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 72: Landroid/app/Activity;.getParentActivityIntent ()Landroid/content/Intent;
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0f1d
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 53 (Landroid/app/assist/AssistContent;) in Lcom/example/dim/myapplication/Create_Apointment;
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0f5b
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 49: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0f7f
    08-30 16:34:26.499 12295-12295/com.example.dim.myapplication I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getContentScene, referenced from method com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.access$super
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dim.myapplication/com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:188)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:170)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:502)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:174)
                                                                                   at com.example.dim.myapplication.Create_Apointment.(Create_Apointment.java:13)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful feel free to comment if something of my question is wrong 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post logcat output when the app stops or crashes

Comment: I have edited with the logcat

Comment: What is Katagrafes? what is Records, above, that how are you calling method that create records using dbhandler class, if you use fragment where is your fragment, there are a lot of to debug, I would like to be friendly here, please read a book like Android Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, it covers Database part very professionally, I will vote to close this question since it is about debugging where a lot of elements missing.

Comment: I rename katagrafes to records so you can understand what is this about. In my code is still with the name "katagrafes" but anyway thank you for the suggestion